# Opposition of Newtons Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How can we be sure that the force exerted by two bodies on each other are equal but in opposite directions? Suppose we have a car and a truck that collide head on with each other. Using principles of momentum it is likely that both the car and the truck will move together at the same velocity in the direction of the truck since the truck exerts a bigger force than the car. If Newtons third law was relevant, both the car and the truck would have come to a stand still as an indication of equal forces exerted in different directions. So the forces will cancel out to zero. But this is not the case, both the car and the truck will move together at the same speed in the direction of the truck, thus indicating that the truck exerted a bigger force on the car hence fnet is in the direction of the truck. So how can we be sure that the force exerted by two bodies on each other are equal in magnitude?

Comment: Because the analogy is faulty. If two cars were involved, they would crash and come to a mutual stop. They do not do so in a car-truck crash, because the truck is held to be carrying more momentum - and therefore the truck is only slowed by the crash, not stopped. The car meanwhile, discharges it's entire momentum whilst absorbing only some of the momentum of the truck.

Comment: Said another way, if you have a car and a truck going the same speed, and you wish to stop them both in the same period of time, you must apply a larger force to the truck than to the car.  Not the same force.  So your statement "both the car and the truck would have come to a stand still" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You say:*"So the forces will cancel out to zero"*. The flaw in this statement is that these two forces operate on two different objects. So you cannot subtract one from another.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of force is $F=ma$.  Since the mass is varied here(a truck is heavier than a car), we also need to vary acceleration so that $F$ is the same.  For instance, if the ratio of the mass of the car to that of the truck is $a:b$, then the ratio of the car’s acceleration to that of the truck is $b:a$.  In this case, then the truck and the car will crash each other head-on with the same force.